# How can I create a 3 time attempt with websockets in python before exiting?

Tags: python, websocket

I've created a script that connects to a websocket and streams data through. Now I'm trying to find a way to use try and except to reconnect to websocket if the stream disconnects or errors out. If the reconnect attempts exceed three time that the script exits. I tried doing it the way shown below but it doesn't work. Is there another way to attempt reconnecting other than using try and except?

```
#!python
from websocket import create_connection

LINK='wss://ws-feed.somestream.com'    
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3 #Max attempts before exiting

attempts = 0 #number of retries

def getStream(LINK):
    ws = create_connection(LINK)
    while True:
        print ws.recv()

try:
    getStream(LINK)

except:
    print "connection error"
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if attempts < 3:
        getStream(LINK)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
try:
    ...
except:
    attempt = 1
    while attempt <=3:
        print "connection error"
        try:
            getStream(LINK)
            attempt = 4
        except:
            attempt += 1
```